# Using the_post() outside of the loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-theme

just a quick one.

I've been given a custom Wordpress theme to replicate for another site, and when digging through the theme files, I noticed that the_post() is being used to output post content without the rest of the loop, i.e. no while(have_posts()) etc. So no the_title(), the_content(), and so on.

Is this a usual practise?? Can't seem to find anything about how or why this works!

If anyone can shed some light for me, that would be brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that it is being used as a template that is called inside of a loop. If you search for references to that file in your project you should find the containing loop.

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but I didn't find anything!

Comment: What is the theme you are using? or was it custom built by a developer ?

Comment: It was a custom-built theme.

Comment: I haven't used them before but it could be a framework like Genesis